# Remove constant after compilation in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

I want to store all texts and properties of my **Nim** program in separate file, like so:

**my.properties:**

```
some=Some
say.hello=Hello world
```

and use those key/values like this:

**my_module.nim:**

```
import properties

const
  some = getProperty("some")
  greeting = getProperty("say.hello")

...
# using of those constants
```

Accordingly, I have written **properties.nim** module to retrieving and parsing properties from properties-file during the compilation.

**properties.nim:**

```
import tables, strutils

const content = "./my.properties".staticRead

proc parseProperties (): Table[string, string] =
  result = initTable[string, string]()
  for line in content.splitLines:
    let tokens = line.split("=")
    result[tokens[0]] = tokens[1]

const properties = parseProperties()

proc getProperty* (path: string): string =
  return properties[path]
```

So, the problem is that I have two **const** variables (**content** and **properties**) in my executable, which I need only during compilation.

How can I, for example, remove theme after compilation or write some sort of macros for that purposes?

**Update**

Thanks to **zah** for so fast answer, so I have rewritten my **properties.nim**:

```
import tables, strutils

let content {.compileTime.} = "./my.properties".staticRead

proc parseProperties (): Table[string, string] {.compileTime.} =
  result = initTable[string, string]()
  for line in content.splitLines:
    let tokens = line.split("=")
    result[tokens[0]] = tokens[1]

let properties {.compileTime.} = parseProperties()

proc getProperty* (path: string): string {.compileTime.} =
  return properties[path]
```

And it works perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace your `content` and `property` constants with regular variables that have the `{.compileTime.}` pragma attached to them. Such variables will be completely eliminated in the generated code.

Comment: I have noticed, that if I compile my first version with **-d:release** Nim's compiler understands what I want and produce the same code in C, which I get when I use **{.compileTime.}** pragma